# Turning a BOUNDED std::list<class> of parameters into a type std::tuple<class,class,class> tup<classObj1, classObj2,classObj2>

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a class

```
class C
{
public:
    C() {}
private:
    int timesTriggered_;

    std::map<std::string, std::tuple<std::string, int, int, int, int, int>> mapST;
    std::vector<std::string> sv;
};
```

and some objects of this type:

```
C c1;
C c2;
C c3;
```

I have a map indexed by strings of class C

```
std::map<std::string, std::list<C>> cMap;
```

I add some objects of class C into a map

```
cMap["1"].push_back(c1);
cMap["2"].push_back(c2);
cMap["3"].push_back(c3);
```

I need a function that when passed the std::list will return (for example with three elements) an

```
std::tuple<C&, C&, C&>(c1, c2, c3)
```

Even though this needs to return an std::tuple, the items of the tuple are always of the same type, C. This has to work no matter how many items in the list there are, although an upper bound of the number of C objects at compile time is fine. So in essence this turns a list (with an upper bound on the number of elements) into a variadic tuple.

Here is a function that returns what I need:

```
template <typename... Obs> std::tuple<Obs &...> BindObservers(Obs &... obs)
{
    return std::tuple<Obs &...>(obs...);
}
```

And it is called like this:

```
auto obs2 = BindObservers(c1, c2, c3);
```

The problem is that to use BindObservers I need to know the number of parameters being passed to it, the things between the commas. I wish there was a BindObservers that worked like this:

```
auto obs2 = BindObservers(std::list<C>);
```

And obs2 would look like (pseudo-code):

```
std::tuple<C,C,more Cs here to the length of std::list<C>>(one parameter for each item in std::list<C> seperated by commas)
```

So it is a kind of template meta-programming.

I need it to work with c++11 since I don't have a c++14 compiler.

Comment: didn't you ask a similar question today? the comments you received still hold

Comment: comments don't run on a computer, or are you saying it is not possible?

Comment: Snark doesn't fetch answers either. Is the number of elements in the `list` bounded? What you're asking for is not possible in the general case. And how is this not a duplicate of your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28612931/241631)?

Comment: Yes the elements in the list are bounded.

Comment: A `std::map` is not variadic on the number of elements, so there is no way to do this in the general case. You could write code to do this manually but that doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: I don't get why it doesn't work in the general case if use the pack operator size and then recurse. Of course if I knew how to use any of this stuff, I would probably get why. I am trying to get a version that works, so I can work towards seeing why the general case does not work.

Comment: `std::tuple<C, C>` is a different type than `std::tuple<C, C, C>`. But `std::list<C>` is always the same type, no matter what number of elements. You could implement such a function only if the number of elements is a compile-time constant. Also `std::array<C, N>` would be better, because tuple is for when the elements have different types.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, in my case C is the only thing ever passed. So even though using tuples, nothing but a std::tuple<C..> is needed. It is not the type that hurts me, it is the variadic nature of how many. See the example of BindObserver in the original post.

Comment: Templates are evaluated at compile time.  If you don't know exactly what is going to be in the list at compile time you can't use it with a tuple since it needs to know the parameters at compile time.

Comment: @Ivan but the number of `C`s may differ depending on the execution of your code, making what you want impossible

Comment: It's impossible in the general case because the number of elements in the `tuple` (which also determines its type) that you want to return from this function must be known at compile time, whereas the size of a `list` can only be determined at runtime. If the list size is bounded (which you now say isn't), say maximum N elements, then create a function that returns a `tuple` having N elements, and if there are fewer elements in the `list` then place some sentinel type in the empty spots (the sentinel may be an instance of `C` with a special value).

Comment: Praetorian, can you give an example with N = 2 say.

Comment: If the number of `C`s is a compile-time constant, maybe you could get using by applying `std::tuple_cat` recursively.

Comment: tmlen exactly. Then recurse. I need an example. Say N = 3. But it has to work if N = 1, 2, or 3. N is an __upper__ bound.

Comment: `std::tuple<C...>` is not a type for any type `C`.  There is no `std::tuple<C...>` in C++.  My advice would be to describe the over-arching problem that led you to think "I need X to and everything will be happy!".  You have asked for the solution to a problem `X`, which you think is the way to solve your real problem `Y`.  Without `Y`, all we can do is (A) guess what you really need, or (B) point out what you are asking for is impossible.

Comment: Then what does BindObservers return above?

Comment: I am being a bit stubborn. I can probably get this to work with some sort of work around. I just can't believe that it can't be done __this__ way.

Comment: @Ivan `BindObservers` is a function template, so it doesn't "return a type".  A given set of parameters passed to `BindObservers` generates a function, which returns a type.  The type returned when you call `BindObservers( 3, 3, 3.14 )` is `std::tuple<int, int, double>`.  `std::tuple<int,int,double>` is a type.  In contrast `std::tuple<C...>` is instructions on how to make a type given a parameter pack of tuples `C`.  The `template` function `BindObservers` uses those instructions, together with the deduced `class...C` pack, to produce the return type.

Comment: therefore if BindObservers is called with BindObservers(object1OfTypeC, object1OfTypeC, object2OfTypeC) its return type is std::tuple<C, C, C>  I don't understand where we are in disagreement. Are you saying it works for built in types and not classes!? NO!

Comment: @Ivan yes.  And `std::tuple<C,C,C>` is a type.  `std::tuple<C...>` is not a type.  You have asked for the function to return `std::tuple<C...>`, but functions return types, not instructions-on-how-to-produce types.  `template` functions can "return" instructions-on-how-to-produce types, but those instructions must be solvable from the types of their template parameters.

Comment: Ah, got it, Sorry I was using ... in the English sense not pack operator. LMAO!

Comment: Please read the example post. Everything is there no need to confuse with these comments.

Comment: @Ivan C++ does not understand English, and you asked for `std::tuple<C...>` as the return type.  Your function must return **one** type for a given set of types of arguments.  **What one type do you want it to return**?  This is mostly pointless, and you'd probably be better off answering the question of "what are you really trying to do?".

Comment: @Ivan This is not possible. If this is not possible, there is something wrong with your design. You probably should wrap your list with a custom class and pass it as an observer itself. Whoever claims *"this is doable with a tuple_cat!!!"* - don't believe them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works correctly on clang and g++ (using C++11):

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8071ab447e10a31

Produces a `std::tuple` with `Max_N` elements of the same type, and fills it up with the first values of the given list. If less elements in list than `Max_N`, fills the last elements with sentinel values.

In practice, using `std::array<C, N>` may be more useful for something like this, if there is a need to pass from a list with a dynamic number of elements to one from a constant number of elements.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<std::size_t Max_N, typename List>
class list_to_tuple {
public:
    using value_type = typename List::value_type;
    using iterator_type = typename List::const_iterator;
    using tuple_type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
        std::tuple<typename List::value_type>(),
        typename list_to_tuple<Max_N-1, List>::tuple_type()
    ));

    tuple_type operator()(const List& lst, const value_type& sentinel) {
        return convert(lst.begin(), lst.end(), sentinel);
    }

    tuple_type convert(iterator_type begin, iterator_type end, const value_type& sentinel) const {
        list_to_tuple<Max_N-1, List> remaining;
        if(begin != end) {
            auto current = std::make_tuple(*begin);
            ++begin;
            return std::tuple_cat(current, remaining.convert(begin, end, sentinel));
        } else {
            return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(sentinel), remaining.convert(begin, end, sentinel));
        }
    }
};

template<typename List>
class list_to_tuple<0, List> {
public:
    using value_type = typename List::value_type;
    using iterator_type = typename List::const_iterator;
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<>;

    tuple_type convert(iterator_type begin, iterator_type end, const value_type& sentinel) const {
        return std::tuple<>();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::list<int> lst = {1, 2, 3};
    list_to_tuple<5, std::list<int>> to_tup;
    auto tup = to_tup(lst, 0);
    std::cout << std::get<0>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<1>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<2>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<3>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<4>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(tup).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me see if I can get a c++14 compiler installed. Would appreciate a c++11 version...

Comment: *"Might work"*. If only there was a tool that could verify if a code compiles fine...

Comment: Almost there!  If I replace   std::list<int> lst = {1, 2, 3}; with std::list<C>  = {c1, c2, c3}; //see original post list_to_tuple<3, std::list<C>> to_tup;    I get error: no match for call to '(list_to_tuple<3ul, std::list<C> >) (std::list<C>&, int)' note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'int' to 'const value_type& {aka const C&}'

Comment: The `0` in `to_tup(lst, 0)` then also needs to be a sentinel value of type `C`.

Comment: Ok got passed that. Now I get std::cout << std::get<0>(tup) << std::endl;    ERRORS: /home/idf/Documents/STD/VariadicTuples/VariadicTupleExample.cpp|75|error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'| /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream|602|error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = C]'|

Comment: The code also does unnecessary copies of the `C`s during the `tuple_cat`. It was just meant as an example.  Does the `C` class have an `operator<<` defined?

Comment: Gotcha. I am gong to figure the rest out the best I can from here. Thank you!

Comment: tmlen, the function I need to pass these tuples to  is: template <template <typename...> class T, typename... Args, typename... Obs>
T<Obs...> MakeSubject(std::tuple<Obs &...> &&obs, Args &&... args)
{
    return T<Obs...>(std::move(obs), args...);
} your function returns objects not object references. Need std::tuple<C&,C&,C&>, not std::tuple<C,C,C>&. Is it still resolvable?

Comment: It should be by altering the `tuple_type` typedef. Maybe `std::reference_wrapper` is needed. Probably would be better to define classes instead of using `tuple` this way.

Comment: I fixed it by removing the & in BindObservers. Now I have a different problem. See here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641836/a-container-that-can-store-variadic-tuple

Answer (score 3):

A list has an undetermined number of elements at compile time.

A tuple has a known number of elements at compile time.

Therefore there is no way for the compiler to deduce the number of elements in the tuple (as it requires information about the elements of the list which is only known during run time).

Try rephrasing a new question with an example with some integers to show what you want to achieve.

Comment: What I want to achieve is given in the original post under "Here is a function that returns what I need:"

Comment: ‘auto‘ needs to be resolved to a type in compile-time. In order to deduce the type you need to derive from some other compile-time known info, for instance another known type or a known number of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

From your question, you want:

```
auto obs2 = BindObservers(std::list<C>);
```

And obs2 would look like (pseudo-code):

```
std::tuple<C,C,more Cs here to the length of std::list<C>>
```

(one parameter for each item in std::list seperated by commas)

The type that a call to the `BindObservers` name (possibly of a `template` function) returns must be fully specified by its template arguments.  In this case, you pass no template arguments, but you do pass a `std::list<C>`.  `BindObservers` can deduce some template arguments from the type of `std::list<C>`.

The types deduced depend only on the type `std::list<C>`.

This means that all calls to `BindObservers` with two different `std::list<C>` must return the same type.

As you want a list of 1 element to return a different type than a list of 2 elements, and two different types are not the same type, this cannot be done.

Now, you could always return a large `std::tuple` with "enough" room up to some limit size.  You could also take a function object, and invoke it with a `std::tuple` of up to some fixed size (where every version is instantiated, but only the correct version is invoked).

But you didn't ask about those possibilities, so the answer is "no, your problem cannot be solved".