# Is there a container that can store items of different types?

Tags: c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

Storing items of the same type is trivial, but I need a container that can store items of different types.

Here's an example showing what I'd like to do:

```
Class C
{
};

C c1;
C c2;
C c3;

std::tuple<C> tup1(c1);
std::tuple<C, C> tup2(c1, c2);
std::tuple<C, C, C> tup3(c1, c2, c3);

container_type container(tup1, tup2, tup3);
```

Is there any container that works in this way? If not, is there a way to create one?

I'd like something that overloads `operator[]` for fast random access.

Comment: What's wrong with a plain tuple ?

Comment: Store what exactly? Your example shows three `C`'s and three tuples of `C`'s.

Comment: See the revised question. I need to store tup1, tup2, or tup3 in the same container. So what is the syntax in std::vector<std::tuple<...>>  ?

Comment: Ok, that helps. Another question - is there any relation at all between `tup1`, `tup2` and `tup3`? Your example shows a very strong relationship. If you are trying to store prefixes, the problem becomes trivial. So getting that out of the way.

Comment: They __all__  have elements of type C. It is because the tuple is variadic that it is giving me trouble. I have a function that returns a variadic tuple and  it needs to go into a container.

Comment: A `vector` is a type-homogenous container. `tuple<C>` and `tuple<C, C>` are different types and can't be held in a `vector` without some type-erasure. Why not use a `vector<vector<C>>`?

Comment: strong typing sometimes really sucks. They are all identical except the number of times C appears in the tuple. I can't really use a tuple to store the tuples because I can't index into a tuple fast. I need a container that has operator[]. Or at worst a hash.

Comment: @Ivan May I ask why you return compile-time sized `tuple`s in the first place, instead of `vector`s ? Variadic templates seem to be the wrong tool for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Because I have an API that is already in place with variadic templates :(

Comment: This seems close http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701397/how-can-i-use-c11-variadic-templates-to-define-a-vector-of-tuples-backed-by-a?rq=1

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790038/c-feed-template-function-element-from-tuple-at-runtime/27790304#27790304) can help you. This may get a bit convoluted though.

Comment: There can't be a `operator[]` that returns different types depending on the index. The index is a runtime variable and the return type is a compile time type. Either use `std::get<i>(tup)` on a `std::tuple` and iterate over it at compile time, or use `std::vector<C>` instead of the `std::tuple<C, C, ..., C>`.

Comment: tmlen the problem is that I am iterating while adding the items to the container. AFAIK, you have to know all the tuple items when you say make_tuple. There is no "push_back" for tuples. There is probably a way to hack it with tuple_cat and continously creating a new tuple from the old one...

Comment: tmlen, the more I think about it, the more the code I need is almost identical to your solution here!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637654/turning-a-bounded-stdlistclass-of-parameters-into-a-type-stdtupleclass-cl

Answer (score 1):

It won't work. You are mixing compile-time polymorphism (the element types and count of a tuple) with run-time polymorphism (you want to store differently sized tuples in a container).

In your example, what should `container[0].get<2>` return? Tuples are guaranteed to be compile-time checked, so there is no runtime information to check whether 2 is a valid index, so throwing an exception or returning a default constructed object can't happen just from using the tuple.

In your example, you are going to copy or move the tuple (when inserting them into the container) anyway, which means you need to copy or move all the elements. You could instead of copying the tuples elements into (new) tuples copy the tuple elements into std::vectors. The function tuple_to_vector would need some template magic to implement efficiently, which I don't have the time to draft up right now.

If you can change the API to return std::arrays instead of std::tuples (which actually guarantee homogenous type and contiguous storage, and provide run-time indexing), a convert-to-vector function would be quite trivial to write.

Answer (score 1):

Run-time polymorphism requires indirection and polymorphic types. What tuples, by their nature, aren't.

What you can do is make your objects part of an inheritance hierarchy, and store in the container (smart)pointers to dynamically allocated objects (dynamic allocation is necessary, since being objects of different types they also have different sizes), or wrap your objects into a class (like `boost::any`, for example) that does "type cancellation", essentially by doing internally the indirection required).

In any case, the container interface, when doing this, will access the pointers or the wrappers. It's up to you to check at runtime the actual type of each referred object before accessing its own specific functions, or to rely only to the virtual function that are common to all.

Comment: Thanks! This hint led to a solution using boost::any.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
auto tuple = std::make_tuple(1, "foo", 3.12);
auto foo = std::get<1>(tuple); // will be a string containing "foo"
```

?

Comment: far more complicated than this. I have to use a variadic tuple and std::initializer_list and then continously use tuple_cat